rust program (server) will remain running, but will close immediately running as a docker image
I have a very simple "Hello world" server that i wrote in RUST, the program is running correctly locally (not as an image), cargo run
Here is my main.rs file -
use axum::{routing::get, Router};
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tracing_subscriber;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let app = Router::new().route("/", get(|| async { "Hello, world!" }));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([0, 0, 0, 0], 3000));
    tracing::debug!("listening on {}", addr);

    axum::Server::bind(&"0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap())
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "axum-project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[dependencies]
axum = "0.5"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
tracing = "0.1"
tracing-subscriber = "0.2"

here is my dockerfile that was generated using docker init
https://forms.gle/ybq9Krt8jtBL3iCk7

ARG RUST_VERSION=1.70.0
ARG APP_NAME=rust-image



FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build
ARG APP_NAME
WORKDIR /app


RUN apk add --no-cache clang lld musl-dev git


RUN --mount=type=bind,source=src,target=src \
    --mount=type=bind,source=Cargo.toml,target=Cargo.toml \
    --mount=type=bind,source=Cargo.lock,target=Cargo.lock \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/app/target/ \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/git/db \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry/ \
    cargo build --locked --release && \
    cp ./target/release/$APP_NAME /bin/server


FROM alpine:3.18 AS final


ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

COPY --from=build /bin/server /bin/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/bin/server"]


Whenever i run the image, ill get 2024-07-10 12:23:01 Hello, world! and the container will shut down.

Are you seeing the Hello, world! in the container logs? Or is that an HTTP response?

It sounds like the process exits when it's running in a container, but not when not running in a container; can you [edit] the question title to clarify this?  In both cases the process is "running on localhost" but "localhost" means something different.

Your code should return Hello world on a GET request to /. Does that mean the server shuts down after the first successful request?

Can you post your cargo.toml?

@chesedo i see Hello world in the container logs.
@Dogbert the server will shut down after this message is printed in to container logs

@Greg0ry
[package]
name = "axum-project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum = "0.5"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
tracing = "0.1"
tracing-subscriber = "0.2"


This sounds a lot like the image is executing the default hello world binary created by cargo init can you delete all images and try to create them fresh?

@yonatanhornstein it's pretty clear then that the binary being started by your container is not the binary that will be produced by the main.rs code you posted. This is because your main.rs never prints "Hello world" to the console.

I modified Dockerfile slightly main.rs and Cargo.toml are the same:
ARG RUST_VERSION=1.70.0
ARG APP_NAME=rust-image

FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build

RUN apk add --no-cache clang lld musl-dev git

WORKDIR /app
COPY src /app/src
COPY Cargo.toml /app

ARG APP_NAME


RUN cargo build --release && \
    cp ./target/release/axum-project /bin/server


FROM alpine:3.18 AS final


ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser
USER appuser

COPY --from=build /bin/server /bin/

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["/bin/server"] 

Then:
cd /path/to/project
docker build -t foo .
docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 foo

in another terminal:
curl localhost:3000

each time I do curl I get Hello world back.
You can work your problem by adding your original bits into Dockerfile one by one, rebuilding and rerunning.

Thank you very much, worked and fixed for me.

If a binary works locally, but not in Docker, then it is almost always a Docker setup issue in my experience.
In your case, you are not copying "into" Docker the local files before building the binary. So you are ending up building some default Rust code which prints out "Hello, world!" instead.
This can be fixed by adding this COPY line to your Dockerfile before the binary is build as follow:
ARG RUST_VERSION=1.70.0
ARG APP_NAME=rust-image

FROM rust:${RUST_VERSION}-alpine AS build
ARG APP_NAME
COPY . /app # Add this line
WORKDIR /app

# The rest of your dockerfile remains the same

